# swift 4 weak variable

Tags: swift, weak-references

In below code, why when car1 variable was assigned nil , car2 is not nil?
Can someone explain it?.I am asking this question because of that I know   when all strong references of a object was assigned nil  , all other weak references are assigned nil automatically.is it wrong?

Thank you so much.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var car1 : Car? = Car()
    weak var  car2 : Car?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        car2 = car1
        car1 = nil
        print("gfehtre")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Car a struct?

Comment: How does the code prove that `car2` is not `nil`?

Comment: @justintime it won't compile if it is a struct. `weak` can only be applied to class-bound protocol types

Comment: @vadian It doesn't but i just checked in playground and it is the case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your question is: `car2` is not nil only when `car2 = car1` is executed on the next line `car1 = nil` `car2` also becomes nil,

Test it yourself by:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let _ = car2 {
        print("first")
    }

    car2 = car1

    if let _ = car2 {
        print("second")
    }

    car1 = nil

    if let _ = car2 {
        print("third")
    }
}
```

You will see in console that only `second` is printed in all other cases `car2` is nil

Comment: I just checked his code on playground and it turned up as not `nil`.

Comment: What gets printed out?

Comment: ""__lldb_expr_17.Car\n"" The same thing when you print car1 with the value.

Comment: No, this code will print only `first` `second` and `third`, so what of these three get printed in your playground?

Comment: second and third

Comment: I tested it in simulator and only `second` is printed, try in simulator instead of in the playground...

Comment: Car object has only one strong reference and when assign it to nil   car2 must be nil because of weak  tag.is it wrong?

Comment: I got it .when I debug  car2 not nil but when you control with let _ = car2  not enter code

Comment: debugger not show car2 nil but when you control in code it is nil

Answer (score 0):

How die you test it in playground? Is `viewDidLoad()` actually called? My code in playground shows `car2` does become `nil`.

```
class Car {
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var car1 : Car? = Car()
    weak var  car2 : Car?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        car2 = car1
        car1 = nil
        print("Is car2 nil?: \(car2 == nil)")
    }
}

let vc = ViewController()
vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

Printed:

```
\\ deinit
\\ Is car2 nil?: true
```